# Can't POST file attachment and data parameters with Python requests lib

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm trying to implement a simple Django view that accept a file attachment and some other parameters and proxy the request on a remote API call.

Please note: the proxy is not the point of my question :)

This is how I implemented the view:

```
def image_upload(request):
    token = request.POST['token']
    image_file = request.FILES.values()[0]

    files = {'file': ('myupload.txt', image_file.read())}

    client_id = request.POST['client_id']
    folder_id = request.POST['folder_id']
    advert_id = request.POST['advert_id']
    image_type = request.POST['image_type']
    crop_image = request.POST['crop_image']

    api_base_url = settings.API_BASE_URL

    file_post_data = {'client_id': client_id, 'folder_id': folder_id, 'advert_id': advert_id,
            'image_type': image_type, 'crop_image': crop_image}

    auth_header = {'Authorization': 'Token ' + token}

    r = requests.post(api_base_url + 'assets/image/upload/', 
        data = json.dumps(file_post_data), 
        headers = auth_header,
        files = files)

    return r.json()
```

The problem is that when I test this view (I use Django Test Client to do it) I get an error on the line "files = files)" that says "**ValueError: cannot encode objects that are not 2-tuples**".

The complete trace log is this one:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_image_upload (fbx.tests.FbxTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrea/Documents/src/fbxapp/onboard/fbx/tests.py", line 18, in test_image_upload
    'image_type': 'A', 'crop_image': False, 'attachment': fp})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 449, in post
    response = super(Client, self).post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 262, in post
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/andrea/Documents/src/fbxapp/onboard/fbx/views.py", line 42, in image_upload
    files = files)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 88, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 324, in request
    prep = req.prepare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 225, in prepare
    p.prepare_body(self.data, self.files)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 385, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 99, in _encode_files
    fields = to_key_val_list(data or {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 136, in to_key_val_list
    raise ValueError('cannot encode objects that are not 2-tuples')
ValueError: cannot encode objects that are not 2-tuples
```

I've also tried a quick test using this to read a file: **files = {'file': ('myupload.txt', open('/tmp/mytmp.txt', 'rb'))}**

but it doesn't work. Do tou have any idea about how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: How about w `files = {'file': image_file.open('/tmp/mytmp.txt', 'rb')}`...note the lack of extra ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot simultaneously post JSON data and `multipart/form-data` which is in essence what you're trying to do here. `json.dumps` returns a string so you're sending a string that looks like

```
'{"client_id": 1, "folder_id": 2, "advert_id": 3, "image_type": "jpeg", "crop_image": true}'
```

And then telling requests you want to use that in combination with a `multipart/form-data` request by sending something in via the `files` parameter. That is impossible and could possibly raise a better exception.

Either add the file to the JSON data after reading it into memory and send that with the appropriate `Content-Type` header or send the entire thing as a `multipart/form-data` request *without* using `json.dumps` and simply passing the dictionary you're creating to `data`. Use one or the other but not both.

That aside, you say that your exception comes from the line that only has `files=files)` on it, but it is not that line alone that causes the exception. The exception is raised by the function which happens to end on that line. The fact that your exception arises from that too is mere coincidence. This is an wart in Python that may possibly be fixed in Python 3.4. You should upgrade, because 3.4 will be awesome and newer versions of Django support Python 3.x.